# How to merge two elements of a list in Rust?

Tags: performance, optimization, rust

I've been working to try to optimize a section of my code and I've hit an area where I think I could use some community wisdom.  I'm essentially trying to merge two elements of a list without moving the elements in the list (via two removes and an insert), because as far as I can tell in Rust doing so to a vector costs O(n) time.

Take a glance at the code that captures the essence of my problem:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

#[derive(PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Num {
    pub num: usize
}

impl Num {
    pub fn new(num: usize) -> Num {
        Num {
            num
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![];
    for i in 0..10 {
        a.push(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Num::new(i))));
    }
    let mut b = BinaryHeap::with_capacity(a.len());
    for i in 0..a.len() - 1 {
        b.push((i, Rc::clone(&a[i]), Rc::clone(&a[i + 1])));
    }

    drop(a);

    while !b.is_empty() {
        let c = b.pop().unwrap();
        let first = c.1;
        let next = c.2;
        println!("c: c.0: {}", c.0);
        println!("c: first.num before: {}", RefCell::borrow(&first).num);
        println!("c: next.num before: {}", RefCell::borrow(&next).num);

        // Here I want to replace the two structs referenced in first and next
        // with a single new struct that first and next both point to.
        // e.g. first -> new_num <- next

        println!("c: first.num after: {}", RefCell::borrow(&first).num);
        println!("c: next.num after: {}", RefCell::borrow(&next).num);
        assert_eq!(RefCell::borrow(&first).num, RefCell::borrow(&next).num);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to take two elements within a list, merge them into one pseudo-element, where the two previous "elements" are actually just pointers to the same new element. However, I'm having trouble finding a way to do this without copying memory or structures around in the list.

Comment: You might be overthinking this, and making it far more complicated than necessary. It's a little bit difficult to see exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps you just need a different data structure, such as a `VecDeque`.

Comment: Something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=76d3cc91046b742fa2877b4b46282c97

Comment: Why are both `Vec` and `BinaryHeap` involved? When you say that you want to edit elements within a list, do you mean the `Vec` or the `BinaryHeap`?

Comment: Peter, that's very much what I'm looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: @michalsrb the original vector is dropped once the heap is created because in my application logic the order that the elements are merged is very critical to correct function. I was playing with the idea of using a heap because I want to minimize the cost of inserting things into the list as my application logic will not always produce things in order.

Comment: This confuses me a lot. In the `while` loop `first` and `next` are no longer members of any list, because `a` has been dropped and you popped them out of `b`. So... you can just reassign them, if you want (`first = new_num; next = new_num;`) and the test will pass. But it sounds like you want to have a side effect on some *other* data structure that isn't shown? Or you want to have a side effect on the other elements of the heap? I don't understand.

Comment: I vote to close your question has unclear since yesterday I don't understand it. Don't hesitate to [edit] it to clarify your question.

Comment: It should not be overlooked that there are multiple references to elements in the heap, so just because an element has been popped out of the heap does not imply that there underlying data has also been popped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your requirement is that you need the `Vec` to be able to hold items that are *either* a value *or* a reference to another item, while keeping the structure *similar* to what you have presented.

We can model that by changing your item type to an `enum`, which can hold either a value or a reference to another item:

```
pub enum Num {
    Raw(usize),
    Ref(Rc<RefCell<Num>>),
}
```

And add methods to include abstractions for constructing the different variants and for accessing the underlying numeric value:

```
impl Num {
    pub fn new(num: usize) -> Num {
        Num::Raw(num)
    }

    pub fn new_ref(other: Rc<RefCell<Num>>) -> Num {
        Num::Ref(other)    
    }

    pub fn get_num(&self) -> usize {
        match &self {
            Num::Raw(n) => *n,
            Num::Ref(r) => r.borrow().get_num()
        }
    }
}
```

If you create a new value like this:

```
let new_num = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Num::new(100)));
```

You can reference it in other nodes like this:

```
*first.borrow_mut() = Num::new_ref(Rc::clone(&new_num));
*next.borrow_mut() = Num::new_ref(Rc::clone(&new_num));
```

The full code then looks like this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

#[derive(PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Num {
    Raw(usize),
    Ref(Rc<RefCell<Num>>),
}

impl Num {
    pub fn new(num: usize) -> Num {
        Num::Raw(num)
    }

    pub fn new_ref(other: Rc<RefCell<Num>>) -> Num {
        Num::Ref(other)    
    }

    pub fn get_num(&self) -> usize {
        match &self {
            Num::Raw(n) => *n,
            Num::Ref(r) => r.borrow().get_num()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![];
    for i in 0..10 {
        a.push(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Num::new(i))));
    }
    let mut b = BinaryHeap::with_capacity(a.len());
    for i in 0..a.len() - 1 {
        b.push((i, Rc::clone(&a[i]), Rc::clone(&a[i + 1])));
    }

    drop(a);

    let new_num = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Num::new(100)));

    while !b.is_empty() {
        let c = b.pop().unwrap();
        let first = c.1;
        let next = c.2;
        println!("c: c.0: {}", c.0);
        println!("c: first.num before: {}", RefCell::borrow(&first).get_num());
        println!("c: next.num before: {}", RefCell::borrow(&next).get_num());

        *first.borrow_mut() = Num::new_ref(Rc::clone(&new_num))
        *next.borrow_mut() = Num::new_ref(Rc::clone(&new_num))

        println!("c: first.num after: {}", RefCell::borrow(&first).get_num());
        println!("c: next.num after: {}", RefCell::borrow(&next).get_num());
        assert_eq!(RefCell::borrow(&first).get_num(), RefCell::borrow(&next).get_num());
    }
}
```

---

As for whether this will prove to be better performance than a different approach, it's hard to say. Your starting point seems quite complicated, and if you can simplify that and use a different underlying data structure, then you should try it and benchmark. I have often been surprised at the actual speed of O(n) operations on a `Vec`, even when the size is around 1000 items or more.

Comment: It should be noted that while it seems over complicated in this example, it represents a more delicate piece of code found at https://github.com/ChosunOne/merkle_bit/blob/stable/src/merkle_bit.rs in create_tree .  I have been benchmarking the results and have so far gained about 30% speed improvements by moving in this direction.  Thank you for your concise answer.

Comment: @ChosunOne Ok, fair enough! Sounds like progress then.